# Can we set the number of items in ListView that it should keep in memory, such that the ListView won't recycle every time

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `listView`, with some very heavy items (Non scrollable `GridView`, and some `TextView`). I have implemented the `ViewHolder` pattern in the adapter but still the scrolling is not smooth. Can we specify in the `ListView`, as to how many items it should keep in memory. I have only 3 items in the `listView` but on scrolling , it always have some discontinuity when a new item come into view.

`Example: Initially 1st child and some portion of 2nd clild is visible, then user scroll, when he is about to hit the 3rd item, there is a slight discontinuity and then 3rd item appear. On scrolling up, the same thing happens when 1st child is about to enter the screen again.`
Can we somehow specify that the `listView` should keep 3 items in memory and dont recycle them, like we do in case of ViewPager(using setOffscreenPageLimit). I know there is no built in support to specify that, but can we extend listView somehow to have such functionality.

Comment: ListView reuses the item views by default, you don't need to do anything, btw view holder pattern has nothing to do with view reusing

Comment: Check [this](http://leftshift.io/6-ways-to-make-your-lists-scroll-faster-than-the-wind) post maybe it helps you on improving your `ListView`

Comment: @pskink I mentioned Viewholder pattern, to make a point that I did everything to make my scrolling smooth. But nothing worked. So, my last resort is to look for loading all the items in memory.

Comment: just use convertView parameter of Adapter.getView method

Comment: Maybe you are doing something wrong. Can you post adapter and its view?

Comment: No you can't do that. What is so heavy in the listview? It might be helpful to show your adapter code and item xml. There may be far easier optimizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question is

**NO**

Do this, set or `View`s `VISIBILTY` to `GONE` and use the `postion` in `getView()` parameter to to know if its the first item or not. Then set the required `View`s for that particular position to `VISIBLE` and all other `View`s to `GONE`

Does it seem helpful to you?

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to say in the explanation but one thing is pretty clear , that we cant really control how many items of the ListView, it should keep in memory. So for solving my problem, I used a scroll View and added the 3 layouts , and now it is scrolling very smoothly.